# Turning on Apache Basic Auth causes server connection failure

Tags: mysql, macos, apache, mamp, basic-authentication

I am trying to test the basic authentication module of apache httpd web server. For some reason when I turn it on, the browser cannot seem to even connect to the server. Details are below. any help will be appreciated.

```
OS: Mac OSX
Apache/Mysql
Browser: Safari
```

I have a mysql db "mydb" storing username and password in a table called "login". Password is encrypted using SHA.

I have a directory structure like

```
/Users/Myname/Sites
/Users/Myname/Sites/Secret
```

I want to secure the Secret folder.

In the httpd.conf I have the following lines

```
DBDriver mysql
DBDParams "dbname=mydb user=admin password=myadminpasswd"

DBDMin  4
DBDKeep 8
DBDMax  20
DBDExptime 300

<Directory "/Users/Myname/Sites/Secret">
 # core authentication and mod_auth_basic configuration                                                                                                                     
  # for mod_authn_dbd                                                                                                                                                       
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "My Server"
  AuthBasicProvider dbd

  # core authorization configuration                                                                                                                                        
  Require valid-user

  # mod_authn_dbd SQL query to authenticate a user                                                                                                                          
  AuthDBDUserPWQuery "SELECT password FROM login WHERE username = %s"
</Directory>
```

After this I restart the apache httpd server. I cannot even access http://localhost anymore.
It gives the following error:
    Safari can’t open the page “http://localhost/” because Safari can’t connect to the server “localhost”.

I was hoping to be able to access localhost but not http://localhost/~myname/Secret

Does anyone has any idea as to what went wrong?

I believe I can access the secret folder via
http://mysername:mypasswd@localhost/~myname/Secret

Notes: I have made sure that the following is loaded in httpd.conf

```
mod_authz_user.so
mod_authn_dbd.so
```

thanks
mbh

Answer (score 0):

Please check your apache server logs and see what errors you get when restarting it with the auth turned on

Comment: In mac web sharing, it is green and it says server is running. But when I look at the error log, I see it did not start at all. No errors either. I removed all of the authentication code. Then it works. To troubleshoot, even if I have the first line: DBDriver mysql - The server does not start according to the error log